# Сократить количество mysql-кода

Tags: mysql, sql, оптимизация

Можно ли как-нибудь сократить количество mysql-кода в следующем запросе?

```
SELECT IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE `field_1` LIKE '1'), 
         (SELECT field_3 FROM tbl WHERE `field_1` LIKE '1'), 
         (SELECT field_3 FROM tbl WHERE `field_2` LIKE '1'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если столбцы `field_1` и `field_2` не уникальны, то подзапросы, в приведенном вами примере, могут вернуть несколько значений. Сам запрос можно сократить до одной выборки из таблицы, что сократит число обращений к таблице:

```
SELECT field_3
FROM tbl
WHERE `field_1` = 1 OR (`field_1` != 1 and `field_2` = 1)
ORDER BY `field_1`
LIMIT 1;
```

Если `field_1` и `field_2` уникальны, то сортировка и ограничение числа записей не нужно:

```
SELECT field_3
FROM tbl
WHERE `field_1` = 1 OR (`field_1` != 1 and `field_2` = 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, у вас во `from` другие таблицы, поэтому вы решили использовать подзапросы в `select`. Можно сделать так при условии, что `SELECT field_3 FROM tbl WHERE field_1 LIKE '1'` возвращает строго 1 строку всегда:

```
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT field_3 FROM tbl WHERE `field_1` = '1'), 
              (SELECT field_3 FROM tbl WHERE `field_2` = '1'));
```

Не стоит делать `like`, если нет необходимости, у вас тут строгое сравнение с единичкой.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. `LIKE` потому, что сравнение на самом деле происходит с текстовым литералом, а единичка тут для упрощения читабельности. ) А первую фразу: "Судя по всему, у вас во `from` другие таблицы, поэтому вы решили использовать подзапросы в `select`", я не совсем поняла...

Answer (score 1):

Сортируем записи, поднимая вверх те, для которых выполняется первое из нужных вам условий, затем второе, и оставляем самую верхнюю (первую) запись выборки.

```
SELECT field_3
FROM tbl
WHERE (field_1 LIKE '1' OR field_2 LIKE '1')
ORDER BY
  field_1 LIKE '1' DESC,
  field_2 LIKE '1' DESC
LIMIT 1
```